# AJAX GET 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, elasticsearch

I am working on a project on Laravel and Elasticsearch. I am beginner to laravel. At one point, I am getting Internal server error in my ajax GET call. My ajax call looks like this.

```
function hint(str)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search1/" + str, // str is argument to be passed to controller function
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.response;
            console.log(this.response);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to call a controller function by passing string argument "str" along with function call. My route call to controller looks like this:

```
Route::get('/search1/{str}','SearchController@search');
```

and my controller function "search" looks like this:

```
public function search($str)
    {
        $client = ElasticSearch::create()->build(); // No error in this line
        $json = '{ // my json data }';
        $param1 = json_decode($json,true);
        //some code to modify a json field to "str";
        echo "something";
    }
```

I would not mind providing any further information regarding my work.

Comment: And what error message do you get, apart of being a 500 error? Maybe you are using csrf validation and you are not including the csrf token in your call?

Comment: @Amarnasan, thanks for reply. This is the only error i'm getting in console. Full error message looks like this " GET http://localhost:8000/search1/abcd  500 (Internal Server Error) " . "abcd" is the input string here.

Comment: Ok, but you sure can check the logs, right?

Comment: @Amarnasan I have no idea about "csrf validation"  but I'm not using any type of validation in input form. If required, I can show my HTML element where "hint" function is being called.

Comment: You can look in the log file for an error message and stack trace. Are you importing the `ElasticSearch` class properly?

Comment: @Felix, thanks for reply. Yes, Elasticsearch class is being imported properly.

Comment: Just check my answer and tell us whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the csrf token in your ajax call:

```
function hint(str)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search1/" + str, // str is argument to be passed to controller function
        data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.response;
            console.log(this.response);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It didn't worked, but i followed your advice of thoroughly checking logs and I found the problem. Actually problem was that i was using JSON object as array without using json_decode. Anyways, thanks for your precious time over my problem